# Epicene pronoun reference resolution ambiguity

Tags: nlp, spacy

**Context:** I am developing resolution strategies of 2nd-person *you* sequences into 3rd-person epicene (gender-neutral, singular) *they* sequences. These are unique recombinable sequences, not unlike a chatbot. The majority, in this case, have been solvable through simple rule-based string replacement with perplexity scoring for objective (*them*) cases, and a distinct strategy for imperative and prohibitive statements.

**Problem:** I am coming up against a seemingly hard limit, however, for sequences that contain both a reference to a plural *they* and the singular epicene *they*. Tokenization and dependency parsing as so far yield little to start with. SpaCy has been my primary software.

(Note in the examples below that were the pronoun not the epicene use of *they* but gendered, the ambiguity would be solved. This is however not an option.)

**Examples:**

1. "When someone plays games with you, they make the rules." *becomes* "When plays games with them, they make the rules."
2. "There are no rules but the ones you make with each other." *becomes* "There are no rules but the ones they make with each other."
3. "Frustration and delays will occur. They will ultimately teach you persistence." *becomes* "Frustration and delays will occur. They will ultimately teach them persistence."

And so on.

**Questions:**

1. Is there anything missing from my understanding of the problem? Am I articulating it adequately?
2. Would coreference modeling be able to sort out the difference between the anaphora?
3. What else should I attempt in order to flag these? I don't need to "resolve" them necessarily.

Comment: You might consider asking this question on [English Language and Usage Stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/). The folks there might not be able to help with the programming part, but I think this is less of a programming question and more of a linguistics question.

Comment: Looks like your question didn't get much traction there, either! That's too bad. Will you try Linguistics as well ?

Comment: @Codebling will attempt, may break it down into more narrow domain-specific questions as well